# Put Wordpress user ID number into a user field

Tags: wordpress, search, advanced-custom-fields

Im using a WordPress theme that has the functionality to search for users on the front end although by default it finds users via their user data/fields such as first name, last name and email etc. But I need to be able to use the same search box to search for users via their User ID number.

And so I was wondering if its possible to create a new user field and automatically put a users ID number into said field. We have a few users already active on the site so it would be great if the fields could be generated and filled automatically for existing users although understand that maybe its something that needs to happen at the point of user registration?

Any help or insight anyone can provide would be amazing and so very much appreciated :)

Many thanks!

Not sure if the search box/input itself can be altered or alternatively if a script can run to generate the user ID number in the user field either all the time of periodically?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! WordPress already assigns an ID number -- a serial number -- to every registered user. Is this the user ID you want to use? Please [edit] your question to tell us a bit more about your requirement: where do your IDs come from?

Comment: Hi O. Jones, thank you so much for the quick response! Apologies for not providing enough details, as you are aware I am new here haha. I'll be sure to edit my post but to answer your question, yep that's the user ID I want to use, the one WordPress already assigns. So I would like to have this ID to be mirrored as a user field, so on each users profile/settings page (/wp-admin/profile.php) there is a field that will automatically be filled with the user ID. Hopefully that makes sense, sorry if not :)

Comment: Your requirement makes sense. To do this you'll have to figure out how to *display* those user id values appropriately.  The inbuilt [WP_User_Query code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_User_Query/prepare_query/#parameters) already searches by user ID when given a numeric search term. You can try this by searching in the dashboard Users panel. It's hard to give more specific advice without knowing how your theme searches from the front-end.